# Implementing multiple Monogame instances(networking)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I'm working in Monogame and want to create a project that contains two separate Monogame "instances"/"games".

The purpose of this is to have one Client/Lobby for creating games and allowing others to join and another for the actual gameplay(I'll also implement networking using the Lidgren library)

So my idea is to have a solution with two projects. One for lobby and one for a game client that two users would be connected to. But that's a separate matter that I'll attempt to tackle another day. First things first, how do I get a Monogame game to start another Monogame project within the same Solution

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific for MonoGame if you want to start another process. You can use Process.Start() from simple .Net

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx